# Javascript Recursion with or operator (||)

Tags: javascript, recursion

FYI: This was an example from the Eloquent Javascript book in Chapter 3.

I've been working through the *"Eloquent Javascript"* book, and I have been wondering how the return works.  Is it going to essentially go through the recursive loop return sequence on the left, then when that side of the recursive loop fails, will it then start the sequence on the right?  I am guessing this because I am under the assumption that javascript has no way to have concurrent/parallel processes like Go.

```
function findSequence(goal) {
    function find(start, history) {
        if (start == goal)
            return history;
        else if (start > goal) 
            return null;
        else 
            return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)"); 
        } 
    return find(1, "1"); 
}
print(findSequence(24));
```

Comment: True.  Javascript does not have threads like Java.  But it does simulate them.  I read this recently and it is a good answer to that part of your question:  http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/.  From John Resig himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  If you have `expression1 || expression2`, then javascript will evaluate `expression1` first and ONLY if it is a falsey value will it then evaluate `expression2`.

The returned value will be the result of `expression1` if it's truthy or if it's not truthy, then the returned value will be the result of `expression2`.

So, in your case, the first `find()` will be called and only if it returns a falsey value will the second `find()` be evaluated and returned.

So, your `return` statement:

```
return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

is logically equivalent to this:

```
var retVal = find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)");
if (!retVal) {
    retVal = find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
}
return retVal;
```

Some examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5NWa9/

FYI - your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with recursion per se.